# Wordpress using file_get_contents in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to open a .p12 key file I placed in the same directory as functions.php. I tried using `file_get_contents()` to open the file, I also tried opening other random files and found that I could not.

```
PHP Warning: fopen(key.p12) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in path/wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php on line 26
```

I've been trying to get around this for hours.

Comment: Can we see the code that you used to try to open the file?

Comment: it's $key =  file_get_contents('key.p12'); key.p12 is in the same directory as functions.php, I really don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't matter that functions.php and key.p12 are in the same directory. It all matters what the running script's working directory is. e.g.

/maindir/subdir/functions.php

```
file_get_contents('key.p12');
```

/maindir/script.php

```
include('subdir/functions.php');
```

In this case, the working directory will be `maindir`, and f_g_c() will be doing the equivalent of `file_get_contents('/maindir/key.p12')`, and fail, because the file is NOT in `maindir`.

Check `getcwd()` at the point you're doing the file_get_contents() call, and check what the working directory really is at that point. You'll probably find it's something completely different than the dir that functions.php lives in.

Comment: seems this works: file_get_contents('.p12', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) can't believe it... 3 hours such a waste of time can't stand wordpress.

Comment: yes, because that forces php to try every directory in the include_path to try and find the file.